# Calculate sum of cells if between date and match keyword

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet of transactions I am trying to auto-populate cells with. I am trying to find entries in a given month and match those entries to a keyword, then add the sum of another cell for that entry.

The data looks like this and is in a separate sheet called 2021E,

| / | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08/11/2021 | Walmart | Groceries | 132.41 |
| 2 | 08/04/2021 | Netflix | Entertainment | 14.66 |
| 3 | 08/02/2021 | McDonalds | Restaurants | 4.49 |
| 4 | 07/28/2021 | Walmart | Groceries | 54.71 |
| 5 | 07/26/2021 | Cenex | Fuel | 37.93 |
| 6 | 08/01/2021 | Western | Pets | 273.46 |
| 7 | 07/22/2021 | NFL | Entertainment | 62.99 |

I can match on keywords in column C and get the sum for those matches from column D with this,

`SUMIFS('2021E'!C:C,"*restaurant*",'2021E'!D:D)`

But I can't seem to think of a way to look for entries for a given month, lets say August, and then calculate the sum for a given keyword such as restaurant.

To be clear here - I'm looking for the total spent (column D) on the category Restaurant (column C) for the month of August (column A).

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below `SUMIFS()` formula. You need to add criteria for dates.

```
=SUMIFS('2021E'!D:D,'2021E'!A:A,">=" & DATE(2021,8,1),'2021E'!A:A,"<=" & DATE(2021,8,31),'2021E'!C:C,"*restaurant*")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, just keep adding criteria to your `SUMIFS`.

In the general case, `=SUMIFS(sum_range, category_range, category, date_range, ">="&monthstart, date_range, "<="&monthend)`

For example, `=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$8, $D$2:$D$8, G3, $B$2:$B$8, "<="&I3, $B$2:$B$8, ">="&H3)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS($D$1:$D$10,$A$1:$A$10,">="&B13,$A$1:$A$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B13,0))
```

Where `B13` is the first of the month you're looking for, e.g. `08/01/2021` for August.

[image]